# Javascript: Angular: Can I combine HTML from both super and subclass?

Tags: javascript, angular

Can I use a template (or some HTML) from a super class's template and combine with HTML from my subclass ?

I've tried with ViewChild in the super and referencing it in the subclass but it's undefined.

Thanks.

Comment: have a look at components they are design to achieve what you are referring to